# Flask REST api resource URLs suggestions

Tags: api, rest, flask, url-routing, restful-url

I'm working on REST Api suing Python Flask, as I have more and more routes, its hard to manage all the resource urls.

Right now, I'm confused which one is better practices of URL parameters. Examples below:

Get a list of courses with limits:
`/courses/<int:lim>` OR `/courses/list?lim=10`

Get a specific course:
`/courses/<code>/<section>` OR `/courses/show?code=cs100&section=1`

Get a list of students in specific course:
`/courses/<code>/<section>/students` OR `/students/show?code=cs100&section=1`

Should I pass query parameters using `/` or by doing `?`

The only reason I'm using `/` is that there's no conflict in query.
If I have these two URL for two different queries, how can I fix it so I can query base on the parameters:
`/students/show?code=cs100&section=1` (Get all students in that course)
`/students/show?id=123456789` (Get the specific student)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL should identify a resource or collection of resources. Any options you want to give the client, such as pagination, limits, filtering, sorting, etc. I think is best to include in the query string or in HTTP headers.

So regarding your specific questions:

> Get a list of courses with limits: `/courses/<int:lim>` OR `/courses/list?lim=10`

Neither one. Use `/courses?lim=10`. No need to have a `/list` component, that is an action, not a resource.

> Get a specific course: `/courses/<code>/<section>` OR `/courses/show?code=cs100&section=1`

The first. Once again, `/courses/show` indicates an action, you want URLs to be links to resources, in this case your course.

> Get a list of students in specific course: `/courses/<code>/<section>/students` OR `/students/show?code=cs100&section=1`

The first, same reason as the previous one.

I have given REST API talks at the last two PyCon conferences, feel free to check them out if you want to learn more API design best practices:

- PyCon 2014: [Writing RESTful Web Services with Flask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px_vg9Far1Y)
- PyCon 2015: [Is Your REST API RESTful?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZYRC8IbCwk)

Comment: I have three collection of resources: Students, Courses, Entries. So the URL should be `/students`, `/courses`, `/entries` and followed by `?querystring`? And for a specific student, it will be `/students/123456789?querystring` as of URL? Do I get it right?

Comment: How can I handle different queries to return then? If there's only one route for that resources.

Comment: Good answer in the main! - I would add that for #3 nesting resources isn't the best way to go about once you pass one or two layers of nesting  - instead use some convention for including foreign-key resources in the query string (see http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes for one way to do it).  The same technique can be used for filtering - `/students?course.code=cs100&course.section=1`

Comment: @SeanVieira Treating the list of students in a class as a query sent to the students collection URL is okay, but it makes the POST request that registers a student to a course a bit odd. You either have to include the query string in the POST request URL (pretty unusual in my opinion), or else you have to send the POST request to a different resource collection that defines all student-to-course registrations, specifying both the student and the course. Doable, but having the nested collection makes it more straightforward.

Comment: Agreed completely - however, you can also send a PATCH or POST request to the student endpoint to update the links between the student and the course (or vice-versa) - see http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating